# Flex layout - cell partially collapses in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got a bit of a weird issue which is happening in Chrome (latest version on Mac). Here is the fiddle which replicates it: http://jsfiddle.net/mwznjnoc/1/

You'll see that the search bar has a set height of 40px. However, as soon as the right side red cell has content which makes it scroll, it squishes the search bar. Moving the search bar outside of the div it is in and under the header div fixes the issue, but I cannot fix it that way (the search bar is part of the view content, which gets rendered in the div it is in). Removing `height: 100%;` from html and body stops it from happening, but is not the fix as I need the viewport height to be 100%. This layout works fine in other browsers I've tested it with, anyone have an idea why this is happening or a way to adjust the layout to prevent it? Thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `flex` rule on your `.search` box.

1. Because it being a part of `flex`, you should remove the style `height:40px` from the `.search` box.
2. Then provide `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` as `0`, and `flex-basis` as `40px`.
3. You may combine all three into one as `flex: 0 0 40px`. This will force the layout to contain the `.search` box within `40px` and let other blocks grow or shrink in the available space.

***Changes in HTML Markup***:

```
<div class="search">search bar</div> <!-- Remove inline style for height -->
```

***Changes in CSS***:

```
.search {
    flex: 0 0 40px;    /* add the flex rule here */
    background: #ccc;
}
```

***Your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mwznjnoc/3/***

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed that, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @JeffWooden: You might get into problems with Firefox though! I am not too sure, but as far as I remember, Firefox has had bugs regarding `overflow` of nested `flex`es. Please do test.